# Django 1.8.3 urls

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I'm new to Django & I'm using version 1.8.3. I'm having trouble with the urls.  I've searched everywhere for an answer and can't find one.  No matter what I do, I keep getting a "NameError" and when I don't get an error, I just get the index.html page.

Both `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`  & `http://127.0.0.1:8000/questions` will render the `index.html` in the templates directory or throw an error.

I would like  `http://127.0.0.1:8000/questions` to render the `home.html` in the `templates/questions` directory and `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` to render the `index.html` in `templates/`.

I have the model registered in questions/admin.py and the app installed in MyProj/settings.py.

folder structure:

```
 MyProj
      |.Python
      |_bin
      |_include
      |_lib
      |_src
      |   |_questions
      |   |    |_ __init__.py
      |   |    |_admin.py
      |   |    |_migrations
      |   |    |_models.py
      |   |    |_tests.py
      |   |    |_urls.py
      |   |    |_views.py
      |   |
      |   |_MyProj
      |   |    |_ __init__.py
      |   |    |_settings.py
      |   |    |_urls.py
      |   |    |_views.py
      |   |    |_wsgi.py
      |   |
      |   |_static_in_pro
      |   |      |
      |   |      |_our_static
      |   |          |_bootstrap
      |   |          |_css
      |   |          |_fonts
      |   |          |_js 
      |   |      
      |   |_templates
      |   |    |_base.html
      |   |    |_index.html
      |   |    |_errors
      |   |    |_partials
      |   |    |_questions
      |   |         |_home.html
      |   |
      |   |_vendor
      |   
      |_static_in_env
              |_media_root
              |_static_root
```

MyProj/settings.py

```
    . . .

    # Application definition



     INSTALLED_APPS = (
            'django.contrib.admin',
            'django.contrib.auth',
            'django.contrib.contenttypes',
            'django.contrib.sessions',
            'django.contrib.messages',
            'django.contrib.staticfiles',
             #third party apps
            'crispy_forms',
            'localflavor',
            'registration',
        #my apps
    #     'jobs',
    #     'likes',
    #     'matches',
    #     'newsletter',
    #     'profiles',
        'questions',
    )

    . . .

    TEMPLATES = [
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
            'APP_DIRS': True,
            'OPTIONS': {
                'context_processors': [
                    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                    'django.template.context_processors.request',
                    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                ],
            },
        },
    ]


    . . .

    # Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

    STATIC_URL = '/static/'

    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_in_env", "static_root")

    STATICFILES_DIRS = (
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static_in_pro", "our_static"),

    . . .
```

MyProj/urls.py

```
    from django.conf.urls import include, url
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.conf import settings
    from django.conf.urls.static import static
    from questions import views, urls
    from .views import IndexView

    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
        url('^.*$', IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
       # url(r'^$', include('questions.urls') ), #Changed here

         url(r'^questions/$', views.home, name='home'),
        #url(r'^questions/$', include(questions.urls)),
    ]

    if settings.DEBUG:
        urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
        urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

MyProj/views.py

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
    from questions import views


    class IndexView(TemplateView):
        template_name = 'index.html'
```

questions/urls.py

```
    from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

    from questions import views

    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^questions$', views.home, name='home'),

    ]
```

questions/admin.py

```
    from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.

from .models import Question, Answer

class AnswerTabularInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Answer

class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [AnswerTabularInline]
    class Meta:
        model = Question

admin.site.register(Question, QuestionAdmin)

admin.site.register(Answer)
```

questions/views.py

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.http import Http404
    from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect

    # Create your views here.

    from .models import Question, Answer

    def home(request):
        return render(request, "questions.home.html", {})
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm missing?  Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 4):

Your url pattern `index` is catching **all** urls. This means that any url patterns below will be ignored.

```
url('^.*$', IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
```

To match only the index (i.e. `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`), change it to

```
url(r'^$', IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
```

Note that I've also added the `r''` prefix to the regex. It doesn't make any difference in this case, but it's a good habit to use it in your regexes.

Comment: Spot on! Just to help with understanding, Django uses something called Regular Expressions (called RegEx) to handle urls. Here is a quick cheat sheet that might help in the future http://www.petefreitag.com/cheatsheets/regex/

Answer (score 0):

In MyProj/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url('^$', IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^questions$', views.home, name='home'),
]
```

questions/urls.py:

```
 urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
]
```

questions/views.py

```
def home(request):
    return render(request, "questions/home.html", {})
```